# GooglePlay: update app and permissions

Tags: google-play, auto-update

I have app on Google play. I was updating app and asking for new permissions.
New permissions require user to agree to update app.
So update does not happen automatically.

app 1.0 - 3 permissions 
app 1.1 - 4 permissions

I wish to create technical update with less permissions but notification to update.
and instantly replace it with normal update

app 1.2 - 3 permissions 
1-5 minutes later
app 1.3 - 4 permissions

Will it work as I wish to update users with app 1.0 with app 1.2 and rest of users with app 1.3

app 1.2 will ask user to update to version 1.3

In theory it should work but in practice don't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default there is only 1 active build.

But if you click "Move to Prod" button then you get second active build.

[image: Google Play screenshot]